# File was uploaded using Explicit FTPS but giving error - ftp_put(): A connection attempt failed

Tags: php, ssl, ftp, xampp, vsftpd

Currently I am working on a website which will have function of uploading files and images.

I have tried `move_uploaded_file` option but it is easily to fail when uploading large files. Then I consider to use **FTP with TLS/SSL Explicit encryption** to instead the `move_uploaded_file`.

However, when I try to upload a large image (> 10MB), I get the follow warning.

```
( ! ) Warning: ftp_put(): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond in U:\xampp\htdocs\php\test.php on line 51
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  438968  {main}( )   ...\test.php:0
2   0.1095  510832  ftp_put( $ftp = class FTP\Connection { }, $remote_filename = 'ftp_dir/file.jpg', $local_filename = 'U:\\xampp\\tmp\\phpB5D1.tmp' )  ...\test.php:51

( ! ) Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in
...
U:\xampp\htdocs\php\test.php on line 51
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  438968  {main}( )   ...\test.php:0
```

It is strange that the image is uploaded to the FTPS server and the SHA256 checksum is exactly the same as the original image.

For small image (< 1MB), only the first error remain.

```
( ! ) Warning: ftp_put(): A connection attempt failed
...
\\tmp\\phpDD31.tmp' )   ...\test.php:51
Success
```

Based on the error, I will have to increase the max_execution_time to solve the second error but I don't have any idea on the first error. The follow code are my PHP file and my FTP server setting.

My PHP website is hosting on Windows 10 PC using XAMPP Control Panel v3.3.0

My FTPS Server is hosting on Rocky Linux 8 VM (VMware Workstation 16 Player) on the Windows 10 PC using vsftpd v3.0.3

The VM use bridge to the host NIC to get the local IP in the same network of the PC

**PHP Code**

```
// set the _FILES array
$ftpToUpload = $_FILES["ftpToUpload"];

// set source path and remote destination path
$source_file_path = $ftpToUpload["tmp_name"];
$file_name = basename($ftpToUpload["name"]);
$dest_file_path = "ftp_dir/$file_name";

// FTPS server IP address
$ftp_conn = ftp_ssl_connect('ftp_server');
            
// define user and password
$user = "rtdftpuser";
$pass = "ftp_password";

//Login
ftp_login($ftp_conn, $user, $pass);
ftp_set_option($ftp_conn, FTP_TIMEOUT_SEC, 600);

//Set passive mode
ftp_pasv($ftp_conn, TRUE) or die("Unable switch to passive mode");

// Transfer file
$transfer_result = ftp_put($ftp_conn, $dest_file_path, $source_file_path);
    
//Verify if transfer was successfully made
if($transfer_result)
{
        echo "Success";                      
}
else
{
        echo "An error occured";
}

// close the ftp session
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
```

**HTML Part**

```
<!DOCTYPE  html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="ftpToUpload" id="ftpToUpload" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png">
            <input type="submit" name="ftpupload" value="FTP Upload">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**vsftpd.conf**

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
xferlog_std_format=NO
data_connection_timeout=600
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_deny=NO
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd/user_list
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
max_per_ip=10

ssl_enable=YES
ssl_tlsv1_2=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
debug_ssl=YES
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
require_ssl_reuse=NO

pasv_enable=Yes
pasv_min_port=40001
pasv_max_port=40100

log_ftp_protocol=YES
```

---------------------------------------- Update 1 ----------------------------------------

I upload a.png via WinSCP on the Windows 10 PC without error

**winscp.log**

```
. 2022-07-16 17:25:53.812 [Background 1] Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:25:54.313 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:25:54.807 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.308 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.743 [Background 1] Size of 1 local files/folders calculated as 468094
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.743 [Background 1] Copying 1 files/directories to remote directory "/ftp_dir/" - total size: 468,094
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.743 [Background 1]   PrTime: Yes+Dirs; PrRO: No; Rght: rw-r--r--; PrR: No (No); FnCs: N; RIC: 0100; Resume: S (102400); CalcS: Yes; Mask: *.*
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.743 [Background 1]   TM: B; ClAr: No; RemEOF: No; RemBOM: No; CPS: 0; NewerOnly: No; EncryptNewFiles: Yes; ExcludeHiddenFiles: No; ExcludeEmptyDirectories: No; InclM: ; ResumeL: 0
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.743 [Background 1]   AscM: *.*html; *.htm; *.txt; *.php; *.php3; *.cgi; *.c; *.cpp; *.h; *.pas; *.bas; *.tex; *.pl; *.js; .htaccess; *.xtml; *.css; *.cfg; *.ini; *.sh; *.xml
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.743 [Background 1] File: 'W:\test\a.png' [2022-03-04T17:37:54.936Z] [468094]
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.743 [Background 1] Copying "W:\test\a.png" to remote directory started.
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.743 [Background 1] Binary transfer mode selected.
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.743 [Background 1] Starting upload of W:\test\a.png
> 2022-07-16 17:25:55.744 [Background 1] TYPE I
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.744 [Background 1] Read 31 bytes
< 2022-07-16 17:25:55.744 [Background 1] 200 Switching to Binary mode.
> 2022-07-16 17:25:55.744 [Background 1] PASV
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.745 [Background 1] Read 53 bytes
< 2022-07-16 17:25:55.745 [Background 1] 227 Entering Passive Mode (xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx,156,106).
> 2022-07-16 17:25:55.745 [Background 1] STOR a.png
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.745 [Background 1] Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:40042 ...
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.745 [Background 1] Connection pending
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.746 [Background 1] Data connection opened
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.746 [Background 1] Read 22 bytes
< 2022-07-16 17:25:55.746 [Background 1] 150 Ok to send data.
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.746 [Background 1] Data connection opened
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.746 [Background 1] Trying reuse main TLS session ID
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.747 [Background 1] Read 16384 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.747 [Background 1] TLS layer changed state from none to connected
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.748 [Background 1] TLS connect: SSLv3/TLS write client hello
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.748 [Background 1] TLS connect: SSLv3/TLS read server hello
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.748 [Background 1] TLS connect: SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.751 [Background 1] TLS connect: SSLv3/TLS write client hello
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.752 [Background 1] TLS connect: SSLv3/TLS write client hello
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.754 [Background 1] TLS connect: SSLv3/TLS read server hello
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.754 [Background 1] TLS connect: TLSv1.3 read encrypted extensions
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.754 [Background 1] TLS connect: SSLv3/TLS read finished
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.754 [Background 1] TLS connect: SSLv3/TLS write finished
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.754 [Background 1] Using TLSv1.3, cipher TLSv1.3: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 4096 bit RSA, TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.754 [Background 1] TLS connection established
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.755 [Background 1] Read 16384 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.755 [Background 1] Read 16362 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.755 [Background 1] Read 16384 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.755 [Background 1] Read 16362 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.755 [Background 1] TLS connect: SSL negotiation finished successfully
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.755 [Background 1] TLS connect: SSL negotiation finished successfully
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.755 [Background 1] Session ID reused
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.756 [Background 1] TLS connect: SSLv3/TLS read server session ticket
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.756 [Background 1] Read 16384 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.756 [Background 1] Read 16362 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.756 [Background 1] Read 16384 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.756 [Background 1] Read 16362 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.757 [Background 1] Read 16384 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.757 [Background 1] Read 16362 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.757 [Background 1] Read 16384 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.757 [Background 1] Read 16362 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.758 [Background 1] Read 16384 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.758 [Background 1] Read 16362 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.758 [Background 1] Read 16384 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.758 [Background 1] Read 16362 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:25:55.810 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:25:56.073 [Background 1] Read 16384 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:25:56.073 [Background 1] Read 16362 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:25:56.314 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:25:56.811 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:25:57.001 [Background 1] Transfer progress: Transferred: 294,714, Left: 0:00:00, CPS: 235,771/s
. 2022-07-16 17:25:57.001 [Background 1] Read 16384 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:25:57.001 [Background 1] Read 16362 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:25:57.072 [Background 1] Read 16384 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:25:57.072 [Background 1] Read 16362 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:25:57.309 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:25:57.814 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:25:58.072 [Background 1] Transfer progress: Transferred: 360,206, Left: 0:00:00, CPS: 154,727/s
. 2022-07-16 17:25:58.309 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:25:58.812 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:25:59.072 [Background 1] Transfer progress: Transferred: 360,206, Left: 0:00:00, CPS: 108,234/s
. 2022-07-16 17:25:59.072 [Background 1] Read 16384 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:25:59.073 [Background 1] Read 16362 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:25:59.316 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:25:59.814 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:00.073 [Background 1] Transfer progress: Transferred: 392,952, Left: 0:00:00, CPS: 90,792/s
. 2022-07-16 17:26:00.073 [Background 1] Read 16384 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:26:00.073 [Background 1] Read 16362 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:26:00.306 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:00.807 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:01.073 [Background 1] Transfer progress: Transferred: 425,698, Left: 0:00:00, CPS: 79,898/s
. 2022-07-16 17:26:01.311 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:01.809 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:02.073 [Background 1] Transfer progress: Transferred: 425,698, Left: 0:00:00, CPS: 67,272/s
. 2022-07-16 17:26:02.073 [Background 1] Read 16384 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:26:02.073 [Background 1] Read 9628 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:26:02.310 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:02.814 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:03.075 [Background 1] Transfer progress: Transferred: 458,444, Left: 0:00:00, CPS: 62,560/s
. 2022-07-16 17:26:03.075 [Background 1] Read 0 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:26:03.307 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:03.808 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:03.913 [Background 1] Read 0 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:26:04.073 [Background 1] Transfer progress: Transferred: 458,444, Left: 0:00:00, CPS: 55,048/s
. 2022-07-16 17:26:04.073 [Background 1] Read 0 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:26:04.312 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:04.810 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:05.075 [Background 1] Transfer progress: Transferred: 468,094, Left: 0:00:00, CPS: 50,181/s
. 2022-07-16 17:26:05.075 [Background 1] Read 0 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:26:05.309 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:05.808 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:06.073 [Background 1] Transfer progress: Transferred: 468,094, Left: 0:00:00, CPS: 45,322/s
. 2022-07-16 17:26:06.073 [Background 1] Read 0 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:26:06.307 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:06.815 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:07.073 [Background 1] Transfer progress: Transferred: 468,094, Left: 0:00:00, CPS: 15,578/s
. 2022-07-16 17:26:07.073 [Background 1] Read 0 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:26:07.314 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:07.812 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:08.073 [Background 1] Transfer progress: Transferred: 468,094, Left: 0:00:00, CPS: 10,788/s
. 2022-07-16 17:26:08.074 [Background 1] Read 0 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:26:08.307 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:08.811 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:09.073 [Background 1] Transfer progress: Transferred: 468,094, Left: 0:00:00, CPS: 10,788/s
. 2022-07-16 17:26:09.073 [Background 1] Read 0 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:26:09.309 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:09.807 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:10.075 [Background 1] Transfer progress: Transferred: 468,094, Left: 0:00:00, CPS: 7,514/s
. 2022-07-16 17:26:10.075 [Background 1] Read 0 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:26:10.314 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:10.808 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:11.074 [Background 1] Transfer progress: Transferred: 468,094, Left: 0:00:00, CPS: 4,239/s
. 2022-07-16 17:26:11.074 [Background 1] Read 0 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:26:11.312 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:11.813 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:12.073 [Background 1] Transfer progress: Transferred: 468,094, Left: 0:00:00, CPS: 4,239/s
. 2022-07-16 17:26:12.073 [Background 1] Read 0 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:26:12.309 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:12.810 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.074 [Background 1] Transfer progress: Transferred: 468,094, Left: 0:00:00, CPS: 965/s
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.074 [Background 1] Read 0 bytes from file
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.307 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.530 [Background 1] TLS layer changed state from connected to closed
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.530 [Background 1] Data connection closed
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.530 [Background 1] Data connection closed
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.530 [Background 1] Destroying data socket after transfer completed
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.530 [Background 1] Transfer completed
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.530 [Background 1] Read 24 bytes
< 2022-07-16 17:26:13.530 [Background 1] 226 Transfer complete.
> 2022-07-16 17:26:13.530 [Background 1] MDTM 20220304173754 a.png
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.531 [Background 1] Read 33 bytes
< 2022-07-16 17:26:13.531 [Background 1] 213 File modification time set.
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.531 [Background 1] Upload successful
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.531 [Background 1] Got reply 1 to the command 4
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.531 [Background 1] Remembering modification time of "/ftp_dir/a.png" as [2022-03-04T17:37:54.000Z]
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.531 [Background 1] Transfer done: 'W:\test\a.png' => '/ftp_dir/a.png' [468094]
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.531 [Background 1] Copying finished: Transferred: 468,094, Elapsed: 0:00:17, CPS: 26,315/s
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.531 [Background 1] Retrieving directory listing...
> 2022-07-16 17:26:13.531 [Background 1] TYPE A
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.531 [Background 1] Read 30 bytes
< 2022-07-16 17:26:13.531 [Background 1] 200 Switching to ASCII mode.
> 2022-07-16 17:26:13.532 [Background 1] PASV
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.532 [Background 1] Read 53 bytes
< 2022-07-16 17:26:13.532 [Background 1] 227 Entering Passive Mode (xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx,156,137).
> 2022-07-16 17:26:13.532 [Background 1] LIST
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.532 [Background 1] Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:40073 ...
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.532 [Background 1] Connection pending
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.533 [Background 1] Data connection opened
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.533 [Background 1] Trying reuse main TLS session ID
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.533 [Background 1] TLS layer changed state from none to connected
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.533 [Background 1] Read 39 bytes
< 2022-07-16 17:26:13.533 [Background 1] 150 Here comes the directory listing.
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.534 [Background 1] TLS connect: SSLv3/TLS write client hello
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.534 [Background 1] TLS connect: SSLv3/TLS read server hello
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.534 [Background 1] TLS connect: SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.537 [Background 1] TLS connect: SSLv3/TLS write client hello
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.537 [Background 1] TLS connect: SSLv3/TLS write client hello
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.540 [Background 1] TLS connect: SSLv3/TLS read server hello
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.540 [Background 1] TLS connect: TLSv1.3 read encrypted extensions
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.540 [Background 1] TLS connect: SSLv3/TLS read finished
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.540 [Background 1] TLS connect: SSLv3/TLS write finished
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.540 [Background 1] Using TLSv1.3, cipher TLSv1.3: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 4096 bit RSA, TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.540 [Background 1] TLS connection established
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.541 [Background 1] TLS connect: SSL negotiation finished successfully
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.541 [Background 1] TLS connect: SSL negotiation finished successfully
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.541 [Background 1] Session ID reused
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.541 [Background 1] TLS connect: SSLv3/TLS read server session ticket
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.541 [Background 1] -rw-r--r--    1 1001     1001       468094 Mar 04 17:37 a.png
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.541 [Background 1] Data connection closed
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.542 [Background 1] Read 24 bytes
< 2022-07-16 17:26:13.542 [Background 1] 226 Directory send OK.
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.542 [Background 1] Directory listing successful
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.542 [Background 1] Got reply 1 to the command 2
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.542 [Background 1] Enriching modification time of "/ftp_dir/a.png" from [2022-03-04T17:37:00.000Z] to [2022-03-04T17:37:54.000Z]
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.542 [Background 1] ..;D;0;1899-12-30T09:00:00.000Z;0;"" [0];"" [0];---------;0
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.542 [Background 1] a.png;-;468094;2022-03-04T17:37:54.000Z;4;"1001" [0];"1001" [0];rw-r--r--;0
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.813 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.813 [Background 1] Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:13.815 Directory content loaded from cache.
. 2022-07-16 17:26:14.307 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:14.810 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:14.810 Sending dummy command to keep session alive.
> 2022-07-16 17:26:14.810 PWD
. 2022-07-16 17:26:14.810 Read 41 bytes
< 2022-07-16 17:26:14.810 257 "/ftp_dir" is the current directory
. 2022-07-16 17:26:15.307 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:15.806 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:16.310 Session upkeep
. 2022-07-16 17:26:16.310 [Background 1] Session upkeep
```

**vsftpd-winscp.log**

```
Sat Jul 16 08:25:55 2022 [pid 1955] [rtdftpuser] FTP command: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "TYPE I"
Sat Jul 16 08:25:55 2022 [pid 1955] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "200 Switching to Binary mode."
Sat Jul 16 08:25:55 2022 [pid 1955] [rtdftpuser] FTP command: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "PASV"
Sat Jul 16 08:25:55 2022 [pid 1955] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,60,173,156,106)."
Sat Jul 16 08:25:55 2022 [pid 1955] [rtdftpuser] FTP command: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "STOR a.png"
Sat Jul 16 08:25:55 2022 [pid 1955] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "150 Ok to send data."
Sat Jul 16 08:25:55 2022 [pid 1951] [rtdftpuser] DEBUG: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "SSL version: TLSv1.3, SSL cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, reused, no cert"
Sat Jul 16 08:26:13 2022 [pid 1951] [rtdftpuser] DEBUG: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "SSL shutdown state is: SSL_RECEIVED_SHUTDOWN"
Sat Jul 16 08:26:13 2022 [pid 1951] [rtdftpuser] DEBUG: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "SSL shutdown state is: 3"
Sat Jul 16 08:26:13 2022 [pid 1955] [rtdftpuser] OK UPLOAD: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "/ftp_dir/a.png", 468094 bytes, 25.70Kbyte/sec
Sat Jul 16 08:26:13 2022 [pid 1955] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "226 Transfer complete."
Sat Jul 16 08:26:13 2022 [pid 1955] [rtdftpuser] FTP command: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "MDTM 20220304173754 a.png"
Sat Jul 16 08:26:13 2022 [pid 1955] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "213 File modification time set."
Sat Jul 16 08:26:13 2022 [pid 1955] [rtdftpuser] FTP command: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "TYPE A"
Sat Jul 16 08:26:13 2022 [pid 1955] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "200 Switching to ASCII mode."
Sat Jul 16 08:26:13 2022 [pid 1955] [rtdftpuser] FTP command: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "PASV"
Sat Jul 16 08:26:13 2022 [pid 1955] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,60,173,156,137)."
Sat Jul 16 08:26:13 2022 [pid 1955] [rtdftpuser] FTP command: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "LIST"
Sat Jul 16 08:26:13 2022 [pid 1955] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "150 Here comes the directory listing."
Sat Jul 16 08:26:13 2022 [pid 1951] [rtdftpuser] DEBUG: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "SSL version: TLSv1.3, SSL cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, reused, no cert"
Sat Jul 16 08:26:13 2022 [pid 1951] [rtdftpuser] DEBUG: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "SSL shutdown state is: NONE"
Sat Jul 16 08:26:13 2022 [pid 1951] [rtdftpuser] DEBUG: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "SSL shutdown state is: SSL_SENT_SHUTDOWN"
Sat Jul 16 08:26:13 2022 [pid 1951] [rtdftpuser] DEBUG: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "SSL shutdown state is: 3"
Sat Jul 16 08:26:13 2022 [pid 1955] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "226 Directory send OK."
Sat Jul 16 08:26:14 2022 [pid 1948] [rtdftpuser] FTP command: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "PWD"
Sat Jul 16 08:26:14 2022 [pid 1948] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "257 "/ftp_dir" is the current directory"
Sat Jul 16 08:26:43 2022 [pid 1955] [rtdftpuser] FTP command: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "PWD"
Sat Jul 16 08:26:43 2022 [pid 1955] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "257 "/ftp_dir" is the current directory"
Sat Jul 16 08:26:44 2022 [pid 1948] [rtdftpuser] FTP command: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "TYPE A"
Sat Jul 16 08:26:44 2022 [pid 1948] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "200 Switching to ASCII mode."
Sat Jul 16 08:27:13 2022 [pid 1955] [rtdftpuser] FTP command: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "PWD"
Sat Jul 16 08:27:13 2022 [pid 1955] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "257 "/ftp_dir" is the current directory"
Sat Jul 16 08:27:14 2022 [pid 1948] [rtdftpuser] FTP command: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "REST 0"
Sat Jul 16 08:27:14 2022 [pid 1948] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "350 Restart position accepted (0)."
Sat Jul 16 08:27:43 2022 [pid 1955] [rtdftpuser] FTP command: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "TYPE A"
Sat Jul 16 08:27:43 2022 [pid 1955] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "200 Switching to ASCII mode."
Sat Jul 16 08:27:44 2022 [pid 1948] [rtdftpuser] FTP command: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "TYPE I"
Sat Jul 16 08:27:44 2022 [pid 1948] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "200 Switching to Binary mode."
Sat Jul 16 08:27:44 2022 [pid 1948] [rtdftpuser] FTP command: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "TYPE A"
Sat Jul 16 08:27:44 2022 [pid 1948] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "200 Switching to ASCII mode."
Sat Jul 16 08:27:44 2022 [pid 1948] [rtdftpuser] FTP command: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "PASV"
Sat Jul 16 08:27:44 2022 [pid 1948] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,60,173,156,70)."
Sat Jul 16 08:27:44 2022 [pid 1948] [rtdftpuser] FTP command: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "LIST -a"
Sat Jul 16 08:27:44 2022 [pid 1948] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "150 Here comes the directory listing."
Sat Jul 16 08:27:44 2022 [pid 1944] [rtdftpuser] DEBUG: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "SSL version: TLSv1.3, SSL cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, reused, no cert"
Sat Jul 16 08:27:44 2022 [pid 1944] [rtdftpuser] DEBUG: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "SSL shutdown state is: NONE"
Sat Jul 16 08:27:44 2022 [pid 1944] [rtdftpuser] DEBUG: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "SSL shutdown state is: SSL_SENT_SHUTDOWN"
Sat Jul 16 08:27:44 2022 [pid 1944] [rtdftpuser] DEBUG: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "SSL shutdown state is: 3"
Sat Jul 16 08:27:44 2022 [pid 1948] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "226 Directory send OK."
```

**vsftpd-php.log**

```
Sat Jul 16 08:45:45 2022 [pid 2241] CONNECT: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy"
Sat Jul 16 08:45:45 2022 [pid 2241] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)"
Sat Jul 16 08:45:45 2022 [pid 2241] FTP command: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "AUTH TLS"
Sat Jul 16 08:45:45 2022 [pid 2241] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "234 Proceed with negotiation."
Sat Jul 16 08:45:45 2022 [pid 2241] DEBUG: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "SSL version: TLSv1.3, SSL cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, not reused, no cert"
Sat Jul 16 08:45:45 2022 [pid 2241] FTP command: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "PBSZ 0"
Sat Jul 16 08:45:45 2022 [pid 2241] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "200 PBSZ set to 0."
Sat Jul 16 08:45:45 2022 [pid 2241] FTP command: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "PROT P"
Sat Jul 16 08:45:45 2022 [pid 2241] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "200 PROT now Private."
Sat Jul 16 08:45:45 2022 [pid 2241] FTP command: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "USER rtdftpuser"
Sat Jul 16 08:45:45 2022 [pid 2241] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "331 Please specify the password."
Sat Jul 16 08:45:45 2022 [pid 2241] [rtdftpuser] FTP command: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "PASS <password>"
Sat Jul 16 08:45:45 2022 [pid 2240] [rtdftpuser] OK LOGIN: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy"
Sat Jul 16 08:45:45 2022 [pid 2245] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "230 Login successful."
Sat Jul 16 08:45:45 2022 [pid 2245] [rtdftpuser] FTP command: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "PASV"
Sat Jul 16 08:45:45 2022 [pid 2245] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "227 Entering Passive Mode (yyy,yyy,yyy,yyy,156,151)."
Sat Jul 16 08:45:45 2022 [pid 2245] [rtdftpuser] FTP command: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "TYPE I"
Sat Jul 16 08:45:45 2022 [pid 2245] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "200 Switching to Binary mode."
Sat Jul 16 08:45:45 2022 [pid 2245] [rtdftpuser] FTP command: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "STOR ftp_dir/a.png"
Sat Jul 16 08:45:45 2022 [pid 2245] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "150 Ok to send data."
Sat Jul 16 08:45:45 2022 [pid 2241] [rtdftpuser] DEBUG: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "SSL version: TLSv1.3, SSL cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, reused, no cert"
Sat Jul 16 08:45:54 2022 [pid 1955] [rtdftpuser] FTP command: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "TYPE A"
Sat Jul 16 08:45:54 2022 [pid 1955] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "200 Switching to ASCII mode."
Sat Jul 16 08:46:03 2022 [pid 2241] [rtdftpuser] DEBUG: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "SSL shutdown state is: SSL_RECEIVED_SHUTDOWN"
Sat Jul 16 08:46:03 2022 [pid 2241] [rtdftpuser] DEBUG: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "SSL shutdown state is: 3"
Sat Jul 16 08:46:03 2022 [pid 2245] [rtdftpuser] OK UPLOAD: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "/ftp_dir/a.png", 468094 bytes, 25.28Kbyte/sec
Sat Jul 16 08:46:03 2022 [pid 2245] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "226 Transfer complete."
Sat Jul 16 08:46:03 2022 [pid 2245] [rtdftpuser] FTP command: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "QUIT"
Sat Jul 16 08:46:03 2022 [pid 2245] [rtdftpuser] FTP response: Client "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy", "221 Goodbye."
```

Comment: Can you upload a file to that FTP server using any commandline/GUI FTP client running on the same machine as your PHP code? If you can, post it's verbose log file.

Comment: @Martin Prikryl Thank you for your reply. I updated the log file.

Comment: Can you please explicitly state whether you run WinSCP on the same machine where your PHP code fails? + Would be better if you post log of a complete WinSCP session.

Comment: Yes, both WinSCP and PHP (XAMPP) are run on the Windows 10 PC.
The Rocky Linux is a VM (VMware Player) which is run on the Windows 10 PC.

Comment: Session Log https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y_AKU9X44kiTrWCTN7BQN7xJE2W6p1t9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It seems that the problem may due to the VMware Player Bridge Virtual NIC. I use a debian VM (in PVE), install vsftpd with the same config and it works.

Comment: Why would it work with WinSCP and not PHP then?

Comment: I don't know, I have also built a debian VM (VMware Player) on the Windows 10 PC, install vsftpd and using the same config but getting the same error. The debian VM (PVE) on my old PC just work. Maybe need to install WireShark to check the TCP packet flow.

Comment: I have also compiled OpenSSL 3 library in the debian VM (VMware Player) on the Windows 10 PC, but still getting the same error. So it is not a OpenSSL version problem.